# How to get URL in $.ajaxSetup ajax interceptor

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created a $.ajaxSetup to intercept all ajax call that i do via $.ajax across application. Using $.ajaxSetup i show and hide spinner for all ajax call across application.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
 beforeSend: function (xhr) {
    $('#loader').removeClass('display-none');
  },
  complete:function(xhr,status){
    $('#loader').addClass('display-none');
  }
});
```

I want to get url so that i can check and prevent spinner for this url: http://graph.facebook.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `this.url` and achieve what you want.

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   beforeSend: function () {
        if(this.url != 'http://graph.facebook.com'){
          $('#loader').removeClass('display-none');
        }
   },
   complete:function(xhr,status){
        $('#loader').addClass('display-none');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly you want to get the url from the ajax call in the ajaxSetup. 
You might want to use a prefilter, like this:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options, originalOptions, jqXHR ) {
  $url = options.url;
});
```